# Is there any website for announcements of journal's special issues?

Tags: journals, website, announcements, special-issue

I was wondering if there is a site or something where I can find announcements for all (most of) the special issues of journals (upcoming and past) . For example of Springer, IEEE, Elsevier, ...

If I search for this now, I find scattered call for papers. Also, I can't seem to find this on wikicfp.

Comment: Are you looking for sites with *announcements* of journal special issues? Or the actual contents of these issues?

Comment: I'd say announcements. I can always google the title then  or go to the publisher's site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is not.

Speaking as somebody who has dealt with a number of special issues on both sides of the editorial table, there is simply too little coherence in how different journals advertise their special issues.  Sometimes it's hard even to find a coherent explanation of how a journal is approaching special issues even on its own website.

Maybe somebody like Google could address this, but it would be a *hard* problem requiring either serious investment in human curation or serious natural language processing mojo.

Answer (score 0):

There are similar services for conferences, but there is no such service (as of yet) for special issue journals.

Hence, the better option at hand would be to periodically and selectively look through publisher sites for special issues.